# Entity Framework Model Property not update properly

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am having below mentioned 2 models.

**GeoLocation** Model :

```
public class GeoLocation {
        public GeoLocation() { }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

**Provider** Model :

```
public class Provider
    {
        public Provider()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual GeoLocation Location { get; set; }

    }
```

**Repository** method :

```
public void SetLocation(string providerKey, GeoLocation location)
        {
            var provider = (from p in Catalog.Providers
                            where p.Key == providerKey
                            select p).Single();

            provider.Location = location;

            Catalog.SaveChanges();
}
```

As like above I need to update Location object of Provider Table.But Above code is giving weird result.That is when incoming **location** object having Id let's say 15.Then I need to update that Id into **provider tables location Id**.But After above code It updates as 16 not as 15.Could you tell me Why ? What is the fundamental issue here ?

Note : I am using **Default EF convention mapping.**

**UPDATE:** I have found the issue here.That is when I put `provider.Location = location;` **GeoLocation** table **Auto increment Id increase by 1**.That is the cause.So How could I avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you get the location? The problem is that your EF context (`Catalog`) believes that the location is a new object to be persisted (= it generates insert into the location table). You must inform catalog that it is already existing object.

This could make a trick:

```
if (location.Id > 0) {
    Catalog.GeoLocations.Attach(location);
} 

provider.Location = location;
```

Comment: Could you give any support for this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364476/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker?noredirect=1#comment26965112_18364476