# Entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am having below mentioned POCO classes.

```
public class AppointmentModel
        {
          public InvoiceDetail InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
          public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
        }


public class InvoiceDetail
    {
       public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    }



public class Invoice
    {
        public Invoice()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried to add that model inside repository is as below.

```
public void Booking(AppointmentModel appointmentModel)
        {

                appointmentModel.InvoiceDetails.Invoice.LatestTotal = latestinvoiceTotal;
                Catalog.Appointments.Add(appointmentModel.InvoiceDetails.Invoice.Appointment);
                 Catalog.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It gives below mentioned error.

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

Stack Trace is as below.

```
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddSingleObject(EntitySet entitySet, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, String argumentName)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Add>b__4()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at PawLoyalty.Data.PetBookings.Repositories.InvoiceRepository.Booking(AppointmentModel appointmentModel) in d:\PawLoyalty Module\New Booking Flow\NewBookingFlow\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Data\PetBookings\Repositories\InvoiceRepository.cs:line 339
   at PawLoyalty.Business.Invoices.InvoiceService.Booking(AppointmentModel appointmentModel) in d:\PawLoyalty Module\New Booking Flow\NewBookingFlow\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Business\Invoices\InvoiceService.cs:line 38
   at PawLoyalty.Business.BookingFacadeService.Booking(AppointmentModel appointmentModel) in d:\PawLoyalty Module\New Booking Flow\NewBookingFlow\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Business\BookingFacadeService.cs:line 152
   at PawLoyalty.Web.Controllers.PetBookingController.BookingProcess(String providerKey, String ownerKey, String serviceId, String petKeys, String selectedDates, String selectedExtraServices, String selectedResourceId, String key, String type) in d:\PawLoyalty Module\New Booking Flow\NewBookingFlow\PawLoyalty\PawLoyalty.Web\Controllers\PetBookingController.cs:line 243
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

**UPDATE**

It's coming through BasicRepository is as below.All repositories have been inherited from this.

```
 public class BasicRepository : IBasicRepository
    {
        private DataCatalog catalog;
        protected DataCatalog Catalog { get { if (catalog == null) catalog = new DataCatalog(); return catalog; } }
        public void Dispose() { if (catalog != null) catalog.Dispose(); }

}
```

Can I have any help ?

Comment: It can happen if the `Appointment` you are adding to `Catalog` has been loaded with or is attached to another context instance than `Catalog` and this other context is not yet disposed.

Comment: @Slauma Could you give more information through simple example?

Comment: @Slauma Actually I am having only one context.That is Catalog.But if any context change has been happened,then How can I add that model into my Catalog context?

Comment: The exception definitely means that more than one context instance is involved. You might have only one `Catalog` *variable* but the question is how you manage its lifetime (when do you call `Catalog = new ...` and when `Catalog.Dispose()` or is there a `using` block for `Catalog`). If you don't dispose the context properly an entity (especially a proxy entity with `virtual` navigation properties) can still hold a reference to the old context (so, it's not garbage collected) while you create a new one. It's hard to tell more details based on your few code snippets...

Comment: @Slauma I am having huge code base with so many inner functions.If you can tell me any specific code snippet, I can provide it.Anyway how can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: The interesting part is how you manage the context lifetime, when do you `new` it up, when do you dispose it, how does the `Catalog` come into the repository?

Comment: @Slauma Plz check my "UPDATE" section.

Comment: Well, you are calling `catalog = new DataCatalog()` in your `BasicRepository`. If you have multiple repos derived from that (maybe an `AppointmentRepo` and an `InvoiceRepo`?) then you have multiple contexts. In order to work with a single context you should create the `DataCatalog` outside the repo and inject it - the same instance - (via constructor) into all repos you are working with.

Comment: @Slauma Yup,Got it.But if you know the url for such a implementation,It will really help for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "Edit" part in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5823230/270591) is a rough sketch ("*Don't do this*" is what you are doing :). "*Instead do this*" is what I meant.). You can also search for "Unit of work and repository". Basically what you have is a repository pattern without unit of work pattern.

Comment: @Slauma Yup,I got huge knowledge about EF by using your 5 or 6 comments. Thanks a lot for your support.Have a nice day !